# Как сделать перемотку аудио в Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt5

У меня проблема.
Кто знает как сделать перемотку аудио в Python и привязать её к QtSlider?
Я использовал pygame и pyqt5, но не нашёл как сделать перемотку...
Как получить длину файла? 
Кто может сказать?
Я буду очень благодарен.

Comment: `QMediaPlayer` и его метод `setPosition(int);`?

Comment: Skip, проблема в том что я не знаю как привязать setPosition к QtSlider

Comment: Могу разве на с++ код написать на QT, т.к. не пишу на QT python

Comment: Опубликуйте пожалуйста минимальный пример демонстрирующий проблему.

Comment: можете посмотреть здесь https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1092494/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%bf%d0%be%d1%87%d0%b8%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b8%d0%b7%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b0-%d0%bd%d0%b0-%d0%ba%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%bf%d0%ba%d0%b0%d1%85-%d0%b0%d1%83%d0%b4%d0%b8%d0%be%d0%bf%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b0

Answer (score 0):

Длина файла в миллисекундах возвращается функцией `QMediaPlayer.duration()`. Но, при определенных обстоятельствах, не сразу, а в процессе воспроизведения, это значение может измениться (как для одного и того же файла, так и при смене файла в листе воспроизведения), поэтому лучше отслеживать сигнал `QMediaPlayer.durationChanged()`.

В слоте отслеживания сигнала изменения длительности медиа-контента можно установить значение `QtSlider` (или `QProgressBar`). В этом же примере добавим перемотку.

```
class SomeParentWidget(QWidget):

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        # необходимые вызовы и инициализации
        # весь gui в self.ui
        #...

        # длительность текущего медиа-контента
        self.mediaPlayer.durationChanged.connect(self.__initSlider)

        # перемотка
        self.ui.slider.valueChanged.connect(self.__rewindTo)

    # duration_ms, миллисекунд (64-битное целое)
    def __initSlider(self, duration_ms):
        self.ui.slider.setMaximum(duration_ms)

    # перемотка
    def __rewindTo(self, pos):
        self.mediaPlayer.setPosition(pos)
```